# Why would just 1 column of aliens move?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am starting to learn Python and I'm not sure what the solution to this would be.This problem happens when i'm doing project ALien Invasion: there just 1 column of aliens moving when I run the program.

alien_invasion.py:

```
import pygame
from setting import Setting
from ship import Ship
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien
import sys
class AlienInvasion:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.setting=Setting()
        self.screen=pygame.display.set_mode((self.setting.screen_width,self.setting.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')
        self.ship=Ship(self)
        self.bullets=pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.aliens=pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.create_fleet()
    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            self.check_event()
            self.ship.update()
            self.update_bullet()
            self.update_aliens()
            self.update_screen()
    def check_event(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            self.check_keydown(event)
            self.check_keyup(event)
    def check_keydown(self,event):
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.ship.moving_right=True
            elif event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.ship.moving_left=True
            elif event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
                if len(self.bullets)<=3:
                    self.fire_bullet()
            elif event.key==pygame.K_x:
                sys.exit()
    def check_keyup(self,event):
        if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.ship.moving_right=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.ship.moving_left=False
    def fire_bullet(self):
        if len(self.bullets)<=2:
            new_bullet=Bullet(self)
            self.bullets.add(new_bullet)
    def update_bullet(self):
        self.bullets.update()
        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.bottom<0:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)
    def create_fleet(self):
        alien=Alien(self)
        available_spacex=self.setting.screen_width-2*alien.rect.width
        number_alienx=available_spacex//(2*alien.rect.width)
        alien_width,alien_height=alien.rect.size
        available_spacey=self.setting.screen_height-3*alien_height - self.ship.image_rect.height
        number_alieny=available_spacey//(2*alien.rect.height)
        for numbery in range(number_alieny):
            for numberx in range(number_alienx):
                self.create_alien(numberx,numbery)
    def create_alien(self,numberx,numbery):
        alien=Alien(self)
        alien_width,alien_height=alien.rect.size
        alien.rect.x=numberx*2*alien_width+alien_width
        alien.rect.y=numbery*2*alien_height+alien_height
        self.aliens.add(alien)
    def update_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.setting.color)
        self.ship.blit()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw()
        self.aliens.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
    def update_aliens(self):
        self.check_fleet_edges()
        self.aliens.update()
    def check_fleet_edges(self):
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.check_edges():
                self.change_fleet_direction()
                break
    def change_fleet_direction(self):
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            alien.rect.y += self.setting.fleet_drop_speed
        self.setting.fleet_direction*=-1
if __name__=='__main__':
    ai=AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

alien.py:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
class Alien(Sprite):
    def __init__(self,ai):
        super().__init__()
        self.setting=ai.setting
        self.screen=ai.screen
        self.image=pygame.image.load('D:/Thinh/alien.png')
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=self.rect.width
        self.rect.y=self.rect.height
        self.x=float(self.rect.x)
    def check_edges(self):
        screen_rect=self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right or self.rect.left <= 0:
            return True
    def update(self):
        self.x += (self.setting.alien_speed*self.setting.fleet_direction)
        self.rect.x = self.x
```

setting.py:

```
class Setting:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color=(0,0,0)
        self.screen_width=1200
        self.screen_height=800
        self.ship_speed=1.5
        self.bullet_speed=1.0
        self.bullet_width=3
        self.bullet_height=15
        self.bullet_color=(255,0,0)
        self.fleet_drop_speed=10
        self.fleet_direction=1.0
        self.alien_speed=1.0
```

bullet.py:

```
class Setting:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color=(0,0,0)
        self.screen_width=1200
        self.screen_height=800
        self.ship_speed=1.5
        self.bullet_speed=1.0
        self.bullet_width=3
        self.bullet_height=15
        self.bullet_color=(255,0,0)
        self.fleet_drop_speed=10
        self.fleet_direction=1.0
        self.alien_speed=1.0
```

ship.py:

```
import pygame
class Ship:
    def __init__(self,ai_game):
        self.screen=ai_game.screen
        self.setting=ai_game.setting
        self.screen_rect=self.screen.get_rect()
        self.image=pygame.image.load('D:/Thinh/ship_1.jpeg')
        self.image_rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.image_rect.midbottom=self.screen_rect.midbottom
        self.x=float(self.image_rect.x)
        self.moving_right=False
        self.moving_left=False
    def blit(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image,self.image_rect)
    def update(self):
        if self.image_rect.right<self.screen_rect.right and self.moving_right:
            self.x+=self.setting.ship_speed
        if self.moving_left and self.image_rect.left>0:
            self.x-=self.setting.ship_speed
        self.image_rect.x=self.x
```

My goal is create alien fleet in the whole screen.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please provide a more clear outline of what the problem you're facing is in general rather than just what your code isn't doing - no one wants to read every single line of your code just to understand what the actual problem is. Where is the function that handles moving the columns? What adjustments have you tried already?

Comment: to make code more readable use spaces around `=` and add empty line before `class` and `def`. See more in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`. It may help to see where is the problem. Maybe you keep only one column on list/group which you use to move aliens.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I run code with`print()` and I checked positions for aliens in `create_alien()` and they are correct but in `check_fleet_edges()` all aliens have `x = 100`. So somewhere in code you set the same `x` for all columns. Maybe all they move to border instead of changing direction.

Comment: if I remove `self.update_aliens()` from `run_game()` then it display all columns. So problem is somewhere in `self.update_aliens()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `self.x`

In `Alien.__init__` you set `self.x = float(self.rect.x)` but when you create aliens then you use `aliens.rect.x = ...` but you don't use `alien.x = float(alien.rect.x)` and finally all aliens have different value in `self.rect.x` but the same value in `self.x`.

And later in `Alien.update()` you set `self.rect.x = self.x` and it moves all aliens to the same column.

You have to use `alien.x = float(alien.rect.x)` when you create alien.

```
        alien = Alien(self)

        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        alien.rect.x = numberx*2*alien_width + alien_width
        alien.rect.y = numbery*2*alien_height + alien_height

        alien.x = float(alien.rect.x)
```

Or maybe you should send `numberx, numbery` to `Alien` - `alien = Alien(self, numberx, numbery)` - and calculate position inside `__init__` before `self.x = float(self.rect.x)`

---

And you may need to remember to use `alien.x = float(alien.rect.x)` everytime when you change `alien.rect.x`.

Or maybe in `Alien` you should create `function` or `@property` which changes both variables.